# How to set this two json array in two spinner in android?

Tags: android, json, spinner

How can I set this type of json response in spinner. In response I have two json array how can i set these two array in different two spinner. like fist spinner have first array value like st1,st2 and second spinner have value with st4,st5,st6.

My Api Response is:

```
   [
  {
    "status": "success",
    "Data1": [
        "st1",
        "st2"
     ],
    "Data2": [
        "st3",
        "st4",
        "st4"
       ]
   }
]
```

And I try

```
   private void getdata(){

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(800000);
        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        client.post("here is my api url", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, 
     cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, String responseString, 
   Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseString, 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, 
    cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                if (responseString != null) {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jaa = new JSONArray(responseString);
                        JSONObject json = jaa.getJSONObject(0);


                        String status = json.getString("status");

                        if (status.equals("success")) {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = 
          json.getJSONArray("Data1");
                            JSONArray jsonArray12 = 
          json.getJSONArray("Data2");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                Data school = new Data();
                                school.setCurrency(jsonArray.getString(i));

          school.setCrpto_currency(jsonArray12.getString(i));
                                btclist.add(school);
                                schoolNames.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                schoolNames12.add(jsonArray12.getString(i));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
    schoolNames));
                    spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> 
     (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
     schoolNames12));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data is not 
      available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet connection", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: so are you getting any error ?

Comment: no i not get any error but value not set in spinner

Comment: spinner1.setAdaper......... refresh spinner like this `spinner1.notifyDataSetChanged();` I think you only need to refresh the adapter , rest things are fine

Comment: take two different for loop for two spinner and try

Comment: only first spinner value set not second

Comment: i try but not work only first spinner value set not both @ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
try {
     JSONArray jaa = new JSONArray(responseString);
     JSONObject json = jaa.getJSONObject(0);

     String status = json.getString("status");

     if (status.equals("success")) {
           JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Data1");
           JSONArray jsonArray12 = json.getJSONArray("Data2");

           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                schoolNames.add(jsonArray.getString(i)); 
                }

           for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray12.length(); j++) {
                schoolNames12.add(jsonArray12.getString(j));
                }
             }
       } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }

spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
    schoolNames));
spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> 
     (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
     schoolNames12));
```

Comment: i also try this. not work only first spinner set value not second

Comment: Check the spinner id in findViewByid(). Is it same or different ?

Comment: what was the issue ?

Comment: i forget change json array  name. your code work for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

used below code check in your code any mistack. make sure data type same in list and array adapter..

```
        // make sure data type are same in list and arrayAdapter
    List<Data> schoolNames=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<Data> dataArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this,MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            schoolNames));
    ArrayAdapter<Data2> dataArrayAdapter2=new ArrayAdapter<Data2>(this,MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            schoolNames12));
    spinner.setAdapter(dataArrayAdapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataArrayAdapter2);
    dataArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dataArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```